# What is the self keyword in Rails helper modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails models, the `self` keyword makes sense. It's referring to the record that is of interest coming from the database.

I've been seeing examples online where `self` is used in helpers and controllers. What does `self` actually represent?

Answer (score 1):

In a module:

`self` in an instance method refers to the instance of the class in which the module is included.

`self` outside of an instance method refers to the module.

Answer (score 0):

`self` represents the current instance of the class.